# Problema hilos concurrencia. Ejercicio de Carrera de hilos. JAVA

Tags: java, hilos

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo uan clase corredor , que lo unico que hace es un metodo `run` (hilo)  que simula la distancia recorrida y va guardandose en la variable distancia que es una sumatoria del resulado de los `Math.Random();`

Mi problema es el siguiente:

¿Como, desde la clase partidos, detecta que uno gana?

He intentado varias cosas como la de crear un metodo en corredor que diga distancia recorrida, pero claro en la clase carrera no se como orientarlo, no he encontrado un ejemplo asi por ahi. Me he creado este ejemplo simple de concurrencia porque se que asi me voy a enterar de las pautas que hay que seguir.

Este es mi código:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class pista_carrera {

    private corredor c1;
    private corredor c2;
    private int meta;

    public pista_carrera(corredor corredor1, corredor corredor2, int meta) {
        this.c1 = corredor1;
        this.c2 = corredor2;
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public synchronized void empezarCarrera() {
        c1.run();
        c2.run();

        while (c1.getDistanciaRecorrida() < meta || c2.getDistanciaRecorrida() < meta) {

        }
    }
}

class corredor extends Thread {

    private int distancia;
    private String nombre;

    public corredor(String nombre) {
        distancia = 0;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - (10 + 1)) + (10));
            distancia += random;
            System.out.println("[" + nombre + "]Ditancia  = " + distancia + " m");
            try {
                sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(corredor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getDistanciaRecorrida() {
        return this.distancia;
    }
}

public class Carrera {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pista_carrera pista;
        corredor corredor1 = new corredor("Ernesto");
        corredor corredor2 = new corredor("Jesus");
        corredor1.start();
        corredor2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, corrígeme si me equivoco, pero creo que tienes mal planteado los hilos. Cuando llamas a corredorN.start(), se ejecuta el método run() automáticamente de tal hilo. Por tanto en el método empezarCarrera utilizar run() en cada objeto crea una doble ejecución de dicho método.

Answer (score 2):

En el código tienes duplicada la funcionalidad de la carrera, así que decidí atacar en un único lugar: en empezarCarrera

```
public class Carrera {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PistaCarrera pista = new PistaCarrera(new Corredor("Ernesto"), new Corredor("Jesus"), 20);
        pista.empezarCarrera();
    }

}
```

La función empezar carrera se queda casi igual. Nota que removí el "synchronized", porque no necesitas que ese pedazo de código este sincronizado, sino el acceso a datos en los threads. También añadí un método para terminar el thread en Corredor

```
    public void empezarCarrera() {

        c1.start();
        System.out.println("Corredor 1, adelante!!!!");
        c2.start();
        System.out.println("Corredor 2, adelante!!!!");

        while (c1.getDistanciaRecorrida() < meta || c2.getDistanciaRecorrida()<meta) {
            //Espera a que todos los corredores terminen (cambiar por && si la carrera termina con un corredor
            /*Dado que java no sabe que c1 y c2 pueden ser ejecutados concurrentemente, 
              este ciclo es optimizado a leer una única vez, pues no se hace nada dentro de el.*/

        }
        System.out.println("Carrera finalizada!!!!");
        c1.terminate();
        c2.terminate();

    }
```

El problema principal en este código es que java optimiza el código, y como getDistanciaRecorrida() vale 0 al iniciar, el programa termina siendo un ciclo infinito. Hay dos formas de solucionar esto: añadir código dentro del ciclo, o **volver "synchronized" getDistanciaRecorrida** para que java no lo optimice (ciertamente, un pequeño hack).

```
public synchronized int getDistanciaRecorrida(){
    return this.distancia;
}
```

Con esto, la clase funciona como esperas.

**NOTA**:
*synchronized* lo que hace es crear una "zona crítica". Es decir, evita que dos threads (hilos) accedan un recurso al mismo tiempo, ya sea una variable o una función. En el caso de este ejemplo, un efecto secundario es que evita ciertas optimizaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Existen muchas implementaciones posibles, pero basicamente todas ellas requieren que en algun momento se sincronicen los threads para informar o su posicion o haber cruzado la meta.

Por ejemplo, en la siguiente implementacion de `Carrera`, se crean los corredores, la pista y se agregan los corredores a la pista.

```
public class Carrera {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Corredor corredor1 = new Corredor("Ernesto");
        Corredor corredor2 = new Corredor("Jesus");

        PistaCarrera pista = new PistaCarrera(20);
        pista.setCorredores(corredor1, corredor2);
        pista.empezarCarrera();
    }

}
```

Por otra parte, un `Corredor`:

- Guarda una referencia a la pista en la que compite

  ```
  void setPista(PistaCarrera pista) {
      this.pista = pista;
  }
  ```
- Si cruza la meta de la pista, le informa a esta ultima que la cruzo y finaliza su tarea (`break` al `while(true)`)

  ```
          if(distancia > pista.getMeta()) {
              pista.cruzarMeta(this);
              break;
          }
  ```

Quedando como:

```
class Corredor extends Thread {

    private int distancia;
    private String nombre;
    private PistaCarrera pista;

    public Corredor(String nombre) {
        this.distancia = 0;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - (10 + 1)) + (10));
            distancia += random;
            System.out.println("[" + nombre + "] Ditancia = " + distancia + " m");
            if(distancia > pista.getMeta()) {
                pista.cruzarMeta(this);
                break;
            }
            try {
                sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Corredor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getDistanciaRecorrida() {
        return this.distancia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    void setPista(PistaCarrera pista) {
        this.pista = pista;
    }
}
```

Y por otra parte, la `PistaCarrera` misma:

- Recibe los corredores y les informa estos en que pista estan

  ```
  public void setCorredores(Corredor c1, Corredor c2) {
      c1.setPista(this);
      c2.setPista(this);
      this.c1 = c1;
      this.c2 = c2;
  }
  ```
- Comienza la carrera y no termina hasta que todos los corredores finalizan (con `join()`)

  ```
  public void empezarCarrera() {
      try {
          c1.start();
          c2.start();

          c1.join();
          c2.join();
          System.out.println("Carrera finalizada");
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(PistaCarrera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
  ```
- Y, lo mas importante, permite a los corredores cruzar la meta. Y aqui es donde es necesario el synchronized para forzar a que solo un corredor cruce la meta al mismo tiempo

  ```
  public synchronized void cruzarMeta(Corredor corredor) {
      if(!hayGanador) {
          hayGanador = true;
          System.out.println("Corredor " + corredor.getNombre()+ " es el ganador");
      }
  }
  ```

Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
class PistaCarrera {

    private Corredor c1;
    private Corredor c2;
    private int meta;
    private boolean hayGanador = false;

    public PistaCarrera(int meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public int getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setCorredores(Corredor c1, Corredor c2) {
        c1.setPista(this);
        c2.setPista(this);
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public void empezarCarrera() {
        try {
            c1.start();
            c2.start();

            c1.join();
            c2.join();
            System.out.println("Carrera finalizada");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PistaCarrera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void cruzarMeta(Corredor corredor) {
        if(!hayGanador) {
            hayGanador = true;
            System.out.println("Corredor " + corredor.getNombre()+ " es el ganador");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 por añadir joins para dar por finalizados los threads